# React Native Target SDK update

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native and currently working on a app that is live on google play store. I updated the targetSdk from 31 to 33 and released the app for internal testing after removing the bugs it had. I did not update all the packages only few.

On android 11 which i am using to test the app it's still showing that the app is made for older version of Android. I have added the account to testers and it also shows on the play store that i am internal tester.

Do i have to update all the packages it is using?
[This is screen shot from the play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Be5T.jpg)

Thank you for your help